# FMXTee unit is now missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

Not sure what I did... 
but now FMXTee is missing from Delphi. When compiling, an error is thrown saying the unit is not found, however, it was working before. Can anyone give some guidance? I would prefer not to do a reinstall of Rad Studio.

Delphi XE8 for FMX

Comment: For which platform are you compiling?

Comment: iOS simulator and iOS Device.

Comment: I am trying to look in the source now under C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\16.0\source but I can't seem to find the unit myself.

Comment: Have you verified that unit is visible to your project, for example in the library path? I looked in XE8 and it doesn't seem to be a standard part of it. I can only find the VCL version. Did you install this as a package?

Comment: No, I did not install this as a package. Was already available when I started using so nothing additional was done to get it working.

Comment: This is the FMX version of TeeChart, correct? My Delphi XE8 Enterprise does not have this component at all - only the VCL one.

Comment: yes, FMX version. Should be labeled FMXTee

Comment: I don't have it. Which edition of Delphi are you using?

Comment: start a new project for iOS. Drop a tChart on the form. Save and then you can see the unit get added.

Comment: using Delphi Xe8 Enterprise version as well

Comment: Does it compile for other platforms, such as Windows?

Comment: Yes, FMX for windows does compile

Comment: Then it sounds like your library path for iOS is missing the location. Look in your Win32 library path for this location, copy it over to the other platforms. That is, unless the FMXTee doesn't support iOS.

Comment: It does support iOS. I've been using it up until this point and I'm still having trouble. Under Tools->Options->EnviormentOptions.DelphiOptions.Library.Librar Path: I've added all the units form win32 that were missing onto iOS simulator, and it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My XE8 is installed to d:\XE8

With a problem like yours, at a command prompt, I go to D:\XE8 and type

```
dir FMXTee*.* /s > dump.txt & notepad dump.txt
```

The result is shown below.  As you can see, there is a FmxTee.DCP file for each target platform.  It's the .DCP file for your target platform that the compiler needs to be able to find via its path settings.  Btw, FmxTee.Dcp isn't a unit, it's a "Delphi compiled package" that contains the Fmx* units used by your project.

```
 Volume in drive D is DriveD
 Volume Serial Number is 0988-CDDC

 Directory of d:\xe8\bin

17/06/2015  23:55         1,381,376 FMXtee9220.bpl
17/06/2015  23:55           804,864 FMXteeui9220.bpl
               2 File(s)      2,186,240 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\bin64

17/06/2015  23:55         1,954,304 FMXTee9220.bpl
17/06/2015  23:55           994,304 FMXTeeUI9220.bpl
               2 File(s)      2,948,608 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\android\release

17/06/2015  23:55           246,565 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         1,032,828 FMXTee.Canvas.o
17/06/2015  23:55           451,119 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            11,996 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            66,476 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.o
17/06/2015  23:55           186,733 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           555,920 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.o
17/06/2015  23:55           114,466 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           387,528 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.o
17/06/2015  23:55         1,571,056 FMXTee.Chart.o
17/06/2015  23:55           138,662 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           487,160 FMXTee.Chart3D.o
17/06/2015  23:55            16,442 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           214,916 FMXTee.Constants.o
17/06/2015  23:55         2,283,321 fmxtee.dcp
17/06/2015  23:55           224,357 FMXTee.Editor.Aspect.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           793,868 FMXTee.Editor.Aspect.o
17/06/2015  23:55           214,874 FMXTee.Editor.Axis.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           800,348 FMXTee.Editor.Axis.o
17/06/2015  23:55           176,834 FMXTee.Editor.AxisIncr.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           539,956 FMXTee.Editor.AxisIncr.o
17/06/2015  23:55           175,911 FMXTee.Editor.AxisMaxMin.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           531,568 FMXTee.Editor.AxisMaxMin.o
17/06/2015  23:55           198,601 FMXTee.Editor.Brush.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           711,424 FMXTee.Editor.Brush.o
17/06/2015  23:55           236,105 FMXTee.Editor.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           855,032 FMXTee.Editor.Chart.o
17/06/2015  23:55           182,231 FMXTee.Editor.CustomShape.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           570,832 FMXTee.Editor.CustomShape.o
17/06/2015  23:55           184,866 FMXTee.Editor.Font.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           572,540 FMXTee.Editor.Font.o
17/06/2015  23:55           179,607 FMXTee.Editor.Formatting.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           576,016 FMXTee.Editor.Formatting.o
17/06/2015  23:55           201,312 FMXTee.Editor.Functions.Gallery.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           660,480 FMXTee.Editor.Functions.Gallery.o
17/06/2015  23:55           233,251 FMXTee.Editor.Gallery.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           818,528 FMXTee.Editor.Gallery.o
17/06/2015  23:55           207,589 FMXTee.Editor.General.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           727,116 FMXTee.Editor.General.o
17/06/2015  23:55           204,254 FMXTee.Editor.Gradient.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           685,020 FMXTee.Editor.Gradient.o
17/06/2015  23:55           204,095 FMXTee.Editor.Legend.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           699,360 FMXTee.Editor.Legend.o
17/06/2015  23:55           175,967 FMXTee.Editor.Margins.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           535,336 FMXTee.Editor.Margins.o
17/06/2015  23:55           198,531 FMXTee.Editor.Paging.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           654,936 FMXTee.Editor.Paging.o
17/06/2015  23:55           179,524 FMXTee.Editor.Panel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           559,756 FMXTee.Editor.Panel.o
17/06/2015  23:55           180,256 FMXTee.Editor.Picture.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           558,900 FMXTee.Editor.Picture.o
17/06/2015  23:55           176,970 FMXTee.Editor.SelectList.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           544,520 FMXTee.Editor.SelectList.o
17/06/2015  23:55           183,438 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Area.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           569,480 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Area.o
17/06/2015  23:55           177,009 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Bar.Stack.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           535,844 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Bar.Stack.o
17/06/2015  23:55           181,850 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Circled.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           557,564 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Circled.o
17/06/2015  23:55           186,783 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Custom.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           583,468 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Custom.o
17/06/2015  23:55           208,963 FMXTee.Editor.Series.CustomBar.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           699,388 FMXTee.Editor.Series.CustomBar.o
17/06/2015  23:55           219,717 FMXTee.Editor.Series.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           178,011 FMXTee.Editor.Series.FastLine.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           541,720 FMXTee.Editor.Series.FastLine.o
17/06/2015  23:55           783,776 FMXTee.Editor.Series.o
17/06/2015  23:55           183,291 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Pie.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           587,768 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Pie.o
17/06/2015  23:55           204,577 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Pointer.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           683,888 FMXTee.Editor.Series.Pointer.o
17/06/2015  23:55           178,198 FMXTee.Editor.Shadow.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           549,832 FMXTee.Editor.Shadow.o
17/06/2015  23:55           203,513 FMXTee.Editor.Source.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           660,692 FMXTee.Editor.Source.o
17/06/2015  23:55           175,721 FMXTee.Editor.Strings.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           532,944 FMXTee.Editor.Strings.o
17/06/2015  23:55           203,247 FMXTee.Editor.Stroke.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           681,532 FMXTee.Editor.Stroke.o
17/06/2015  23:55           177,647 FMXTee.Editor.Symbol.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           544,352 FMXTee.Editor.Symbol.o
17/06/2015  23:55           178,798 FMXTee.Editor.TextShape.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           550,768 FMXTee.Editor.TextShape.o
17/06/2015  23:55           177,707 FMXTee.Editor.Title.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           545,296 FMXTee.Editor.Title.o
17/06/2015  23:55           178,041 FMXTee.Editor.Wall.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           550,716 FMXTee.Editor.Wall.o
17/06/2015  23:55           830,930 FMXTee.Engine.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         2,618,844 FMXTee.Engine.o
17/06/2015  23:55             5,586 FMXTee.Html.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            68,516 FMXTee.Html.o
17/06/2015  23:55             3,304 FMXTee.o
17/06/2015  23:55           302,892 FMXTee.Procs.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         1,007,116 FMXTee.Procs.o
17/06/2015  23:55            69,622 FMXTee.RadioGroup.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           144,420 FMXTee.RadioGroup.o
17/06/2015  23:55           277,727 FMXTee.Series.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         1,055,568 FMXTee.Series.o
17/06/2015  23:55         7,308,417 fmxteeui.dcp
17/06/2015  23:55             3,316 FMXTeeUI.o
             100 File(s)     50,947,656 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\iosDevice32\release

17/06/2015  23:55           245,723 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           482,144 FMXTee.Canvas.o
17/06/2015  23:55           451,120 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            11,996 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            41,360 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.o
17/06/2015  23:55           186,734 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           278,904 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.o
17/06/2015  23:55           114,463 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           193,852 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.o
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           766,968 FMXTee.Chart.o
17/06/2015  23:55           138,665 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           250,668 FMXTee.Chart3D.o
17/06/2015  23:55            16,442 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           126,064 FMXTee.Constants.o
17/06/2015  23:55         2,283,270 FMXTee.dcp
[etc]
             101 File(s)     34,032,459 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\iosDevice64\release

17/06/2015  23:55           248,532 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           519,136 FMXTee.Canvas.o
17/06/2015  23:55           461,734 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            12,011 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            44,824 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.o
17/06/2015  23:55           192,022 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           294,272 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.o
17/06/2015  23:55           117,137 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           203,692 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.o
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           817,188 FMXTee.Chart.o
17/06/2015  23:55           141,337 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           267,760 FMXTee.Chart3D.o
17/06/2015  23:55            16,442 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           108,956 FMXTee.Constants.o
17/06/2015  23:55         2,339,338 FMXTee.dcp
[etc]
             101 File(s)     35,290,089 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\iossimulator\release

17/06/2015  23:55           545,099 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           819,348 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            29,677 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           255,514 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            88,922 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           199,094 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            61,029 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         4,584,154 FMXTee.dcp
              53 File(s)     14,909,723 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\osx32\debug

17/06/2015  23:55         2,800,906 FMXTee.dcp
17/06/2015  23:55           899,179 FmxTeeUI.dcp
               2 File(s)      3,700,085 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\osx32\release

17/06/2015  23:55           452,754 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           707,774 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            28,317 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           200,615 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            86,283 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           147,784 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            60,937 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         2,726,086 FMXTee.dcp
[etc]
              51 File(s)      8,573,066 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\win32\debug

17/06/2015  23:55         2,801,135 FmxTee.dcp
17/06/2015  23:55           896,098 FmxTeeUI.dcp
               2 File(s)      3,697,233 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\win32\release

17/06/2015  23:55           371,995 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           581,778 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            24,274 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           169,068 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            71,509 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           124,712 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            53,088 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         2,729,047 FmxTee.dcp
[etc]
              51 File(s)      7,770,259 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\win64\debug

17/06/2015  23:55         3,868,744 FmxTee.dcp
17/06/2015  23:55         1,189,260 FmxTeeUI.dcp
               2 File(s)      5,058,004 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\lib\win64\release

17/06/2015  23:55           617,116 FMXTee.Canvas.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           953,818 FMXTee.Chart.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            38,589 FMXTee.Chart.Functions.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           261,006 FMXTee.Chart.GalleryPanel.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55           116,447 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55             1,616 FMXTee.Chart.ListBox.Style.res
17/06/2015  23:55           197,049 FMXTee.Chart3D.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55            54,632 FMXTee.Constants.dcu
17/06/2015  23:55         3,794,633 FmxTee.dcp
[etc]
              51 File(s)     11,517,678 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\Redist\win32

17/06/2015  23:55         1,381,376 FMXTee9220.bpl
17/06/2015  23:55           804,864 FMXTeeUI9220.bpl
               2 File(s)      2,186,240 bytes

 Directory of d:\xe8\Redist\win64

17/06/2015  23:55         1,954,304 FMXTee9220.bpl
17/06/2015  23:55           994,304 FMXTeeUI9220.bpl
               2 File(s)      2,948,608 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
             522 File(s)    185,765,948 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  458,163,204,096 bytes free
```

Comment: Okay, so I can do that or go to that path manually and I can confirm the right .dcp and .dcu files are there. How exactly would I correct this in Delphi Path settings, now?

Comment: Go to Project Manager, select your Build Configuration, right click it and select Edit from the context menu.  That'll take you to where you can adjust paths, etc.  Oh, and resist the temptation to move any files around to get it working!

Comment: If you still haven't solved this, please add to your q a) the Uses list from your unit which will not compile and b) the *exact* error message you get, including the error number.

Comment: I got it solved last night, late. I had installed a third party component that once I removed from the library path, then the FMXTree units were able to be found again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and for anyone else facing a similar issue, you can launch the IDE with the option "-rtest" as explained here to get reverted back to defaults temporarily:

http://support.embarcadero.com/article/42597